# Handling non-existent observableArray properties in the view in KnockoutJS

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

How do I show an `observableArray`'s property in the view without getting a ReferenceError when that property disappears?

For example, I have the following `observableArray`:

```
this.arr({a:1, b:2, c: ['qwe', 'qweq'], d:4});
```

And I'm trying to show the length of `c` in the view:

```
<div data-bind="with: arr()">
  <div data-bind="text: c.length"></div>
</div>
```

This works on page load, but when I empty the array, I'm getting the ReferenceError in the console.

**Example**: http://jsfiddle.net/074pxwzt/

Is there a way to just ignore the property in case it doesn't exist?

Comment: Why do you set the observableArray to an object? It seems you should either use an `observable` for this, or actually use it as an array: `this.arr( [ {a:1, b:2, c: ['qwe', 'qweq'], d:4} ] );`. In that case you'll have to iterate over the contents with a `foreach` binding, though.

Comment: @janfoeh that's proper advice. You should incorporate that into your answer too. Either use `observable` and set it to `null`, or use an actual *array* in an `observableArray`.

Comment: @Jeroen you're right - I only stumbled over that after writing the answer. I've updated it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `with` binding does not bind its children if the property does not exist / is null.

I am confused as to why you set the `observableArray` to an object, though — it seems you should either use an observable for this, or actually use it as an array.

**Version with `observable`:**

```js
var ViewModel = function() {
  var self = this;

  this.arr = ko.observable();

  this.arr({
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: ['qwe', 'qweq'],
    d: 4
  });

  this.kill = function() {
    self.arr(null);
  }

};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div>

  <button data-bind="click: kill">Kill</button>

  <br>
  <br>

  <div data-bind="with: arr">
    <div data-bind="text: c.length"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Version with `observableArray`:**

```js
var ViewModel = function() {
  var self = this;

  this.arr = ko.observableArray([]);

  this.arr.push({
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: ['qwe', 'qweq'],
    d: 4
  });

  this.kill = function() {
    self.arr.removeAll();
  }

};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div>

  <button data-bind="click: kill">Kill</button>

  <br>
  <br>

  <div data-bind="foreach: arr">
    <div data-bind="text: c.length"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for your specific case. However if you set the array to null using this code then it will then error.

```js
var ViewModel = function() {
  var self = this;

  this.arr = ko.observableArray();

  this.arr({
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: ['qwe', 'qweq'],
    d: 4
  });

  this.kill = function() {
    self.arr([]);
  }

  this.swap = function() {
    self.arr({
      a: 1,
      b: 2,
      x: ['qwe', 'qweq', 'ijdj'],
      d: 4
    });
  }

};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div>
  <button data-bind="click: kill">Kill</button>
  <button data-bind="click: swap">Swap</button>
  <div data-bind="with: arr().c">
    <div data-bind="text: length"></div>
  </div>
  <div data-bind="with: arr().x">
    <div data-bind="text: length"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```